# MediaCodec - strange error when sending EOS buffer into audio decoder

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm working on replacing the audio track of my video with music from another file. So I modified the standard `ExtractDecodeEditEncodeTest` code (from bigflake) so that the audio `MediaExtractor` is created from said 'another file'. A strange thing happens when I try to send an EOS buffer into the audio decoder, however, in this line:

`this.audioDecoder.queueInputBuffer(decoderInputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);`

This netted me an `android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffff3`.

When I caught it in a try-catch-finally loop, it's apparently an `android.media.MediaCodec.error_neg_13` (code: -13). The video still came out seemingly fine, however, with the replaced audio track.

As far as I searched, there is nothing about this error ,not even in the logs. Does anyone know what causes it and how I can prevent it from happening?

Comment: how did you resolved this issue finally?

Answer (score 9):

You get the `android.media.MediaCodec.error_neg_13` if the `MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM` is sent in a buffer that contains data to be processed instead of in an empty buffer.

My solution was to send the `MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM` in a separate buffer not containing any data.

During my research of this error i did not find any reference to the `android.media.MediaCodec.error_neg_13`, not even in the libstagefright source code so i'm not sure if this is the only cause.

Comment: Apparently it's safer to send the EOS into the Encoder from the Decoder instead of from the Extractor to the Decoder. So I moved that EOS sending thing into the `audioEncoder.queueInputBuffer()` phase instead.

Comment: That is true, but if you need only parts of the input file you cant get around signaling the EOS when you need it. BTW, if you find a solution to your problem, post an answer to help others with the same problem

Comment: This helped immensely. I came here from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307164/why-the-mediacodec-codecexception-in-queueinputbuffer-only-happen-on-android/60571854#60571854, and the way I chose to adapt existing code to use a separate buffer was to add an infinite wait, e.g. `DECODER.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to avoid the error by sending the EOS flag into the Encoder only after checking the `presentationTimeUs` in the decoder output buffer info, instead of doing it when queueing the decoder's input buffer.

The code:

```
if(presentationTime < totalTime) {                            
    audioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(encoderInputBufferIndex, 0, size, presentationTime, audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo.flags);
} else {
    audioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(encoderInputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM); }
```

That code is executed after processing the audio buffer, and `presentationTime` and `size` are changed from the original `audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo`. Basically, between getting the decoder's output buffer and sending the data into the encoder's input buffer - not before sending the extracted data/sample into the decoder's input buffer.

NOTE: Let me know if the full portion of the code is needed.